# This crap question will self-destruct in

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [off-topic questions should be deleted rather than closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86046/off-topic-questions-should-be-deleted-rather-than-closed)

When a question is closed 'off topic' and not migrated, there's a pretty good chance that it's a dud. After giving it a reasonable period of time for a possible edit/reopen process, why not allow it to encounter the event horizon and disappear?

Comment: Not sure this is a dupe.  Grace's answer to the marked dupe seems to indicate that the manual deletion process is unreliable, and so a self-destruct seems like it could be a good solution.  Closed questions don't need to stay open until manually deleted if there's no activity.